# How to conditionally run commands in Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I'm passing the "RUNNING_LOCALLY" arg from docker-compose and based on that I want to run different commands.

When it's true I want to run `npm run build and npm run serve`. When it's false I want to set up ENTRYPOINT, but there is a problem because the first part is working, but even after serving the app is still building and the part with entrypoint is wrong too.

This code earlier was working like a charm:

```
npm run build
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"
```

Currently I have something like:

```
ARG RUNNING_LOCALLY

RUN if [ "$RUNNING_LOCALLY" = "true" ]; \
    then \
        npm run build \
        && \
        npm run serve; \
    else \
        ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/app"]; \
    fi
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this. What is a point of RUNNING LOCALLY like this? IFs in the Dockerfile forces it to be rebuild each time, so you lose caching possibilities. Do you really think it's necessary to run stuff locally in docker? If so, maybe you should simply use volumes to start your project in docker but you don't really need to serve your app like this

Comment: Write a script, in that script check the variable, add the script unconditionally to ENTRYPOINT

Comment: There's really no need for this, as it doesn't run at build time and you can override the entrypoint or command at runtime.